# How can I use two arrays in foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays which I stored in earlier as

```
foreach($data as $test_data)
{
 $arr1[] = $test_data['val1'];
 $arr2[] = $test_data['val2'];
}
```

Now I want to use that two arrays in another foreach loop is there a way??

I tried the following approach but it is not working:

```
foreach($arr1 as $data1 and $arr2 as $data2)
{
 echo $data1;
 echo $data2;
}
```

Here I need value from both array to insert it into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo $arr2[$key];
}
```

or you can use `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
    echo $arr1[$i];
    echo $arr2[$i];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for previous comment :(, I fix one error and than this will work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can store your both values like this,

```
foreach($data as $test_data)
{
 $arr['arr1'][] = $test_data['val1'];
 $arr['arr2'][] = $test_data['val2'];
}

for ($i=0; $i< count($arr); $i++)
{
    echo "val1 = ".$arr['arr1'][$i];
    echo "val2 = ".$arr['arr2'][$i];
}
```

Comment: I run this script in back-end and for testing I added code to send a mail with this variables but I didn't get any mail. If I remove this foreach than everything works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

if the two arrays has the **same length**,maybe you can do this:

```
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value){
    $arr1[$key];
    $arr2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly the same processing that the 'foreach' is doing but on the second array. Using the iterator that all arrays have.

[Working code at eval.in](https://eval.in/453821)

```
<?php

$a1 = array('a1k1' => 'a1v1', 'a1k2' => 'a1v2', 'a1k3' => 'a1v3');
$a2 = array('a2k1' => 'a2v1', 'a2k2' => 'a2v2', 'a2k3' => 'a2v3');

reset($a2); // indicate what the code will use...
            // do exactly what the `foreach` loop is doiung

foreach($a1 as $a1Key => $a1Value) {

 $a2Key   = key($a2);
 $a2Value = current($a2);


 echo '<br />', 'a1Key: ', $a1Key, ' a1Value: ', $a1Value;
 echo '<br />','a2Key: ', $a2Key, ' a2Value: ', $a2Value;

 next($a2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this kind of 2 or more array then you can try by this simple way

```
$data1= array('val1'=>'yes','val2' => 'no');
$data2= array('val3'=>'yes','val4' => 'no','val5' => 'go');

$data = array_merge($data1,$data2);
foreach($data as $key => $val)
{
 echo $val."<br>";
}
```

I used here array_merge function